# if one of the matrix row is zero how can I find the Vector?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Kindly I am trying to find A, B, C, D in the matrix below so I could find the vector but I am stuck in this matrix

$$
\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&-1&1\\0&0&-2&1}
\pmatrix{A\\B\\C\\D}=
\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\0}
$$

I don't know how to deal with

Answer (score 0):

Let us call $M$ the given matrix.

The question can be reformulated as "find the kernel $K$ of $M$".

1. The rank of $M$ is $3$: it is not 4 because $\det(M)=0$ but one can find a submatrix (the $3 \times 3$ lower left block) with non zero determinant ; said otherwise, the rank is 3 because the first three columns of $M$ are independent.
2. Therefore the dimension of $K$ is $4-3=1$ (by [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)).
3. One can verify that $V=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ belongs to $K$.
4. As a consequence, the general solution is

$$\begin{pmatrix}A\\B\\C\\D\end{pmatrix}=kV=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-k\\k\\2k\end{pmatrix}$$